# Cannot create property label on string error on immutable objects probably

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string

I am getting an error which I am not able to understand or shake. What I am trying to do is that on click of a button I am trying to change the value in the text field in the form I created Howerver I am getting this error:

Cannot create property label on string for one of the instances.

[image]

Here is the function where I am trying to change the values:

```
getReport(ReportList) {
    
   
    this.state.SPCCODE.label = 'NA';
    
this.state.destinationcode.label = 'NA'
    
  }
```

I am declaring SPCCODE in the state as

```
SPCCODE: '',
destinationcode: '',
```

I am declaring SPCCODE as conditional render in render like so:

```
let DDL;

    const DDLValue = servicecode.label;
    

    if (DDLValue == 'Direct') {
      DDL = <> </>;
    } else if (DDLValue == 'STYD') {
      DDL = <> </>;
    } else {
      DDL = (
        <Col lg="6" style={{ marginTop: '0rem' }}>
          <Label for="spcc">SPC</Label>
          <Select
            className="select"
            id="spc"
            // value={servicecode}
            placeholder="Search spcCode..."
            value={hide ? null : SPCCODE}
            onChange={this.handleChangeSPC}
            options={this.state.spcCode}
            isDisabled={this.state.disable}
            styles={{
              control: (provided, state) => ({
                ...provided,
                boxShadow: 'none',
                // borderBottom: "1px dotted pink",
                borderBottom: this.state.isEmpty4 ? '1px solid red' : '1px solid black',
              }),
            }}
          />
        </Col>
      );
    }
```

I am handling the SPC CODE change in this function:

```
handleChangeSPC = SPCCODE => {
    this.setState({ hide: false });
    this.setState({ SPCCODE });
    var spc_label = SPCCODE.label;
    this.setState({ spc_label });
  };
```

I am calling the g getReport() function from a child component table like this

```
passVariable() {
    
    this.props.getReport(this.state.ReportList);
  }
```

I am calling this onClick

On researching I am getting that may it is showing the error because the variable is immutable but have not anywhere declared it in const. Please help do not know why exactly this error is showing?

Comment: String values cannot have properties; they are not objects.

Comment: I have declared other variables as such which I have not mentioned in the function and they work out just fine, what do you think I should do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you declare `SPCCODE` as string in the state then trying to access to non-existent property `label` inside it. It is not possible and throw type error.

To solve it, you must declare it like literal object such as:

```
SPCCODE: {label:''}
```

Comment: Doesnt reactselect have property of label and value inside it?

Comment: Its working thanks but why are the other values not working like this and why do i need to declare this specifically?

Comment: Of course reactselect have these property inside it. According his api it must be declare list of key value object structure like this ‘[{ value: 'value', label: 'label' },]‘. 
All depends of the declaration inside you state and what you intend to do with. By default you'll just have to handle select value.

Comment: but other variables are handled in the same way and no problem arose strange??

Comment: What variables are you talking about ? please show me one of these

Comment: hi @Diskary, I updated the question in which destinationcode works the same way without having to add anything . PLease see and answer

Comment: It won't work due the same reason of type error.  Your script execution break 
 at SPCCODE  because it declare first in getReport function.
TypeScript is more restrictive on data type.

Comment: No that code works I have a running model of it there was a problem with just SPCCODE